# Best practices for setting up developer access to Azure Resources

Tags: powershell, azure

**I would like to find out what the best practices are for managing developers' access to a sub-set of resources on a client's subscription?**

I've searched Google and the Azure documentation looking for definitive answers, but I have yet to come across an article that puts it all together. Because Azure is still developing so rapidly I often find it difficult to determine whether a particular article may still be relevant.

**To sum up our situation:**

I've been tasked with researching and implementing the Azure infrastructure for a web site our company is developing for a client. At the moment our manager and I have access to the client's entire subscription on the Azure Portal by means of the Service Administrator's credentials, even though we're managing only:

1. Azure Cloud Service running a Web-Role (2-instances with Production and Staging environments).
2. Azure SQL Database.
3. Azure Blob Storage for deployments, diagnostics etc.

We're now moving into a phase where more of the developers in the team will require access to perform maintenance type tasks such as performing a VIP swap, retrieving diagnostic info etc.

What is the proper way to manage developer's access on such a project?

The approach I've taken was to implement Role Based Access Control (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/)

1. Move 1, 2, and 3 above into a new Resource Group according to http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/03/24/moving-resources-between-azure-resource-groups/
2. Creating a new User Group for our company, say "GroupXYZ".
3. Adding the "GroupXYZ" to the Contributor role.
4. Adding the particular developer's company accounts to "GroupXYZ"

**Motivation for taking the role-based approach**

1. From what I understand giving everyone access as a Co-Administrator would mean that they have full access to every subscription in the portal.
2. Account-based authentication is preferable to certificate-based authentication due to the complexity added by managing the certificates.

What caused me to question my approach was the fact that I could not perform a VIP swap against the Cloud Service using PowerShell; I received an error message stating that a certificate could not be found.

Do such role-based accounts only have access to Azure by means of the Resource Manager Commandlets?

I had to switch PowerShell to the Azure Service Manager (ASM) Mode before having access to the Move-AzureDeployment commandlet.

Something else I'm not sure of is whether or not Visual Studio will have access to those resources (in the Resource Group) when using Role Based Access Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply RBAC to Azure as you have or just in general, give access to an account via RBAC, then those accounts can only access Azure via the Azure Resource Manager APIs, whether that's PowerShell, REST or VS.

VS 2015 can access Azure resources via RBAC when using the 2.7 SDK.  VS 2013 will have support for it soon.

Comment: Thank you bmoore-msft. It seems like we'll have to use certificates for the VIP swap until such time it is supported in  the Azure Resource Management API's.

It does seem like Microsoft is pushing the idea of Resource Groups for Azure. [Overview of Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/)